# How to change the format of an Image upload field in Web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

Suppose i have an Upload field for an Image (like - Profile Picture) for a record , so my questions is that how will i be able to change the format of that picture ? 
I would also love to use the PIL or PythonMagick API , but how would i do that in Web2py ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a **profile** table, and an **image** table
Then, you have a controller to edit a profile image.
By "change the format of the picture", I suppose you want to resize the image, of create a thumbnail...
Here is an example using PIL :

```
def edit_image():
    """
        Edit a profile image, creates a thumb...
    """
    thumb=""
    profile = db.profile(request.vars.profile_id)
    image = db(db.image.id==profile.image).select().first()
    if image:
        form = SQLFORM(db.image, image, deletable=True, showid=False)
        thumb = image.thumb
    else:
        form = SQLFORM(db.image)
    if form.accepts(request.vars, session): 
        response.flash = T('form accepted')
        #resize the original image to a better size and create a thumbnail
        __makeThumbnail(db.image,form.vars.id,(800,800),(260,260))
        redirect(URL('images'))
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = T('form has errors')
    return dict(form=form,thumb=thumb)
```

Here is the code of **__makeThumbnail**

```
def __makeThumbnail(dbtable,ImageID,image_size=(600,600), thumbnail_size=(260,260)):
    try:    
        thisImage=db(dbtable.id==ImageID).select()[0]
        from PIL import Image
    except: return

    full_path = path.join(request.folder,'static','images', thisImage.file)
    im = Image.open(full_path)
    im.thumbnail(image_size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save(full_path)
    thumbName='thumb.%s' % (thisImage.file)
    full_path = path.join(request.folder,'static','images', 'thumbs',thumbName)
    try: 
        im.thumbnail(thumbnail_size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
    except:
        pass
    im.save(full_path)
    thisImage.update_record(thumb=thumbName)
    return
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help but what I want is image type conversion like from jpeg to eps .

Comment: Seems that PIL cannot manage eps files. But you should be able to do the trick using ImageMagick command "convert image.eps image.jpg" ( see http://stackoverflow.com/a/107861/2714427 )